# How do I unlock the Team Fortress 2 familiars?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I preordered Dungeon Defenders on Steam, but I can't seem to find the preorder DLC anywhere. Has anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: Related: I bought the game on steam (not preordered). I found the TF2/Portal crates in my tavern in open mode, but not ranked. One of the recent updates mentioned moving the crates out of the "secret room". After this update, I found the crates in my ranked tavern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find them in a box in your Tavern ingame. There will be level requirements on each item.

- The TF2 Familiars are only usable after you hit level 25.
- The Portal gun for the Huntress is usable from level 30.

Comment: actually the portal gun requires hero level 30

Comment: @yx. Correcting now. I was on a class that wasn't the Huntress when I checked, and I didn't realize it didn't give me the proper level.

Comment: There's just something weird about walking up to a grown Russian man and storing him in your item box.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its added automatically.  The packs are called Elite Gear Pack, and Advanced Technology Pack.  Every one of my friends that I gifted a prepurchase order to has shown that " now owns Elite Gear Pack, Advanced Technology Pack" on my community page.

What do you get when you click on the "Download Content" button inside the main menu of the game?